# Vertical alignment WITHOUT absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I'm working on this data table, and the 2 items in the top are dynamic in nature and may or may not be the same size relative to other data tables of this type. I'm attempting to vertically align these items to the bottom of their container WITHOUT using absolute positioning. I've tried it, and while it does move the content to the bottom, it removes it from the flow of the layout which wreaks havoc on my layout when you start re-sizing the screen, as I have a fluid layout. So I need another option for getting this to work, if one exists.

Here is a `[jsfiddle]`(http://jsfiddle.net/0ox71q84/) showing my issue. This is set up as though I had absolute positioning in place. The data in data1 is so large that it's pushed the upper 2 cells in the table clear off the page.

Are there any alternative options for me getting these things where they should be?

**EDIT:** I didn't clearly mention this in my OP, but the reason I designed my table this way is because I want it to be very fluid. When you re-size the screen past a certain point, everything "collapses" and all the elements line up vertically, as opposed to side-by-side. By the very nature of tables, I can't do that with 2 different table cells, but elements WITHIN a table cell I can work with. Why a table in the 1st place? I was trying to use the `Vertical-alignment:bottom` thing that apparently only works with tables. I tried using `display: table-cell` on my original div's, but it didn't work, so I switched the whole design to a table and it still doesn't work. Everything else works fine, I have no problem with the table (that I'm aware of), it's just this vertical aligning thing . . .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.  Please clarify if it isn't.

I took off the absolute positioning in the css, so it looks like this:

```
#data1 {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
}

#img {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I added some jQuery that made the picture go to the bottom.  You can apply it to the table too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).resize(function(){
        $('#img').css('margin-top', $('#data1').height() - $('#img').height());
    }); // resize
}); // ready
```

Also, I must really suggest you use divs instead of tables, especially for a responsive layout.  They are far easier to make into tables than tables are.

UPDDATE:

To include jquery, put this code somewhere inside the head tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After that (but still inside the head tag), you can use the function by also putting it inside the script tags:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).resize(function(){
        $('#img').css('margin-top', $('#data1').height() - $('#img').height());
    }); // resize
}); // ready
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I used an actual browser to test this code instead of jsfiddle.  Sorry about the confusion earlier.  You can copy and paste this code into the head tag.  Let me know if it works for you:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function myFun(){
    $('#b-image').css('margin-top', $('#b-info2').height() - $('#b-image').height());
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        myFun();
    }); // resize
}); // ready
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    myFun();
}); // ready
</script>
```

Comment: I really haven't done any javascript, jQuery or any of that sort, so I'm a bit unsure as to how to try out that code you just gave me. I cant tell where the ID's go, but the rest confuses me. How would I plug that in and mess with it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to add jquery.  I also have made a demo in https://jsfiddle.net/0ox71q84/3/

Comment: Ok, so I did as you said, put all that inside the <HEAD> of the page I'm using this on, and then I changed the #ID's to what they actually are in my CSS (which is #b-info2 & #b-image). However nothing changed. It clearly did something in the jsfiddle (don't understand how but that's ok) but it's not having any effect on my code . . .

Answer (score 0):

I believe using jQuery or JS isn't needed.

I tinkered with your fiddle a bit.  I think your issues are more related to not having your table properly structured.  The image was in a place that made it difficult to manipulate it.

Try moving the image up inside the row with the data that is overflowing.  Get rid of the absolute positioning completely.  Then create some column classes so you can set your spacing appropriately.

Then you can use a media query to check the size of the device.  Not knowing exactly how you want it to look, you can use this to get you started:

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px) 
{    
    table, tbody, tr, td {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This will cause your table to start stacking up vertically when the screen gets smaller.

There is a good example here:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: There's actually a reason the table is structured that way. See **Edit**